# hidden values are not passing in form action

Tags: php, forms

When I save this form all `type="text"` fields are working fine. But hidden field values are not passing.

If I changed from "hidden" to "text" it works fine. I don't know why I am getting this problem.

```
<form  action="../model/meter-reading-model" method="POST">

<input type='hidden' name='hdnTakenDate' id='hdnTakenDate' value='<?php echo $TakenDate; ?>' />

<input type='hidden' name='hdnSiteHeadDbKey' id='hdnSiteHeadDbKey' value='<?php echo $SiteHeadDbKey; ?>' />

<button type='submit' name="btnSaveData" id="btnSaveData" class='btn btn-lg btn-danger'> Save Reading Data </button>
</form>
```

Receiving in another page

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    if(isset($SaveData)){   
        $TakenDate = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['hdnTakenDate']);
        $SiteHeadDbKey = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['hdnSiteHeadDbKey']);   
    }               
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `mysqli_real_escape_string($conn`?

Comment: I can't see any reason for it. What do you see if you do `var_dump($_POST);`? Have you checked the Network tab of DevTools to see the whole form submission?

Comment: You are wide open for [SQL Injection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/). Since you're using [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), take advantage of [prepared statements](https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection) This will take care of any pesky quoting issues that may occur. When a query does not work the way you expect, check for [mysqli errors](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php) to see if there's an issue. Even [escaping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187) the string is not safe!

Comment: When I checked $_POST value I am getting all values except hidden fields. If I change hidden to text I got all values.

Comment: Do the fields actually have a value when you view the source, before submission?

Comment: yes value is present when I am debugging the code.

Comment: Are the hidden inputs inside a hidden DIV?

Comment: Thanks @Barmar. yes input fields are inside hidden Div for that reason it was not working. when I shifted to outside hidden div it's working fine. Thanks once again.

Comment: My research says that they're supposed to be submitted, but it was a change to the HTML spec a few years ago. Current browsers should do the right thing.

Answer (score 0):

It solved for me when i change this

```
<input type='hidden' name='hdnTakenDate' id='hdnTakenDate' value='<?php echo $TakenDate; ?>' />

<input type='hidden' name='hdnSiteHeadDbKey' id='hdnSiteHeadDbKey' value='<?php echo $SiteHeadDbKey; ?>' />
```

to this

```
<input type='hidden' name='hdnTakenDate' id='hdnTakenDate' value='<?php echo $TakenDate; ?>' **/>**

<input type='hidden' name='hdnSiteHeadDbKey' id='hdnSiteHeadDbKey' value='<?php echo $SiteHeadDbKey; ?>' **/>**
```

Comment: Thanks Joseph but this was not working for me and stars are displaying on page.

Comment: @ManoranjanJena  i ment by stars extra space from right and left and try to clear your `cache` by clicking `ctrl + shift + R `